# Find sublist of second largest elements in a list (Python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-manipulation

Given a list:

```
lis = [37.21, 37.21, 37.2, 44, 44, 44, 101, 101]
```

What is a simple way to extract the second-largest elements?

> ```
> [44, 44, 44]
> ```

### My attempt

```
lis = [37.21, 37.21, 37.2, 44, 44, 44, 101, 101]
def sublist_of_second_largest(lis):
    maxx=max(lis)
    n=lis.count(maxx)
    for i in range(n):
        lis.remove(maxx)
    maxx=max(lis)
    n=lis.count(maxx)
    out=[]
    for i in range(n):
        out.append(maxx)
    return out

print(sublist_of_second_largest(lis))
```

Comment: Always try to use snake_case when naming variables and functions. see [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While [Zain's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62359828/9248793) is correct and consice, due to the sorting it has an O(n log n) runtime. This might not matter to you, but if it does here is an O(n) implementation:

```py
def sublist_of_second_largest(num_lst):
    num_set = set(num_lst)
    num_set.remove(max(num_set))
    snd_largest_num = max(num_set)
    return [val for val in num_lst if val == snd_largest_num]

print(sublist_of_second_largest([37.21, 37.21, 37.2, 44, 44, 44, 101, 101]))
```

Prints:

```py
[44, 44, 44]
```

Answer (score 3):

Simple pythonic way:

```py
lis = [37.21, 37.21, 37.2, 44, 44, 44, 101, 101]
num = sorted(set(lis), reverse=True)[1]
print([i for i in lis if i == num])
```

**Ouput:**

> [44, 44, 44]